# InvalidArgumentException on Laravel controller testing

Tags: laravel, laravel-testing

In my Laravel project I have this test:

```php
    /** @test */
    public function tagControllerStore()
    {
        $this->post(action([TagController::class, 'store']), [
            'name' => 'My tag',
            'type' => 'My type',
            'color' => 'white'
        ])
        ->assertOk();
    }
```

This is my controller and the store method in it:

```
<?php

namespace Domain\Shared\Http\Controllers;


class TagController extends Controller
{

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(StoreTagRequest $request, Tag $tag)
    {
        $tag = Tag::create($request->validated());

        return response()->json([
            'id' => $tag->id
        ]);
    }
}
```

And the result is this:

```
InvalidArgumentException: Action Domain\Shared\Http\Controllers\TagController@store not defined.
```

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: do you have a store mthod on ```TagController::class```

Comment: Yes, I have it.

Comment: add the code of the store method with the namespace of the class and the class to your question.

Comment: @N69S I did, I just left the use lines.

Comment: if your controller is in the right folder `Domain/Shared/Http/Controllers/` or you have associated the folder with the namespace in your composer.json file then do `composer -dumpautoload` and try your test again.

Comment: It's the same after it.

Answer (score 0):

The action function will generate the url based on the defined routes, did you add a route with action `[TagController::class, 'store']`?

Comment: I added it in a middleware group with resources:

Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth:api'], function () {
  Route::resources([
    'tag' => TagController::class
    ]);
});

Comment: If your controller route not declarations to use the standard PHP callable syntax, the `$namespace` property within your `RouteServiceProvider` will used to automatically prefix controller route declarations.

Comment: I deleted that prefix, and change the namespaces manually where it's necessary.

Comment: Then you may need to check the route cache file in `bootstrap/cache`, check the routes about `tag`. If the cache file does not exist, you can run `php artisan route:cache`. By the way, you'd better clear your route cache after deleting the prefix.